# Save radar chart in R

Tags: r, save, radar-chart

I would like to save the radar chart but cannot do so. Below is my code.

```
library(fmsb)
png(filename ="plt.png")
radarchart(g3, axistype=1,
           pcol=colors_border, 
           pfcol=colors_in,seg=4,
           plwd=3 ,plty =1,pty = 32,cglcol="grey", cglty=1, cglwd=1, vlcex=1,
           maxmin=TRUE, centerzero = T, 
           axislabcol="black",  vlabels = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"))
```

However, the graph saved out is blank. Could anyone help?

Thanks very much!

Comment: We need to close png, add `dev.off()` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `dev.off()` at the end of your R script and it should work ok.